# Found published work that doesn't reference previous related work

Tags: publications, citations, errors-erratum

I have been researching a specific topic in computer science for a couple of years now and a well established professor and his students have recently published a couple of publications in that topic too. In their work they do reference the well known and well cited previous work that basically everyone in that topic references, but I have noticed that they ignore (don't reference) a couple of publications that are doing essentially what they are publishing about, i.e. extremely related work. And I am wondering even though there is a gap of a couple of years between the work they have published and the available previous literature how did they miss referencing the relevant previous work? Was it done intentionally or did they just do a hasty job at finding more recent related work?

Either way my main concern here is if there is anything that can be done to remedy the situation now, since the paper has already been published?

Comment: 1) "_Was it done intentionally or did they just do a hasty job at finding more recent related work?_" - this is a question that only the authors can answer. 2) "_Is there anything that can be done to remedy the situation?_" - why? Are those ignored papers yours? If so, write to the authors and point them to the relevant works. If not, I'd say there's no point in taking any actions. But if you really want to: write to the authors and point them to the relevant works.

Comment: @corey979 one of them is mine the other one isn't. How should I write that email? "Hey by the way you missed to reference this and this paper in your x publication as they are essentially doing the same thing you are trying to do in x"

Comment: They can't update the references of a published article. The best they can do is citing those references in the next related paper.

Comment: So their literature survey was not perfect ... tough, many many papers could show similar omissions. They can’t do much except go forward and neither can you...

Comment: Email: "Dear X, I saw your interesting paper on Y. You might be interested in the following paper of mine on Y that addresses a similar question."

Comment: @Michael Greinecker that would actually be a good answer.

Comment: "they ignore (don't reference) ..." why do you assume that the lack of a reference is due to a decision to ignore? To ignore something means to refuse to take notice of it. Your very way of phrasing the question assumes malice on the part of these researchers.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Realistically, there is nothing you can do to change an already published paper. There are some options for extreme cases, but they are unlikely to apply.

What you can do is try to have the record correct in future publications. Unless you have hard evidence to the contrary (and usually even then), it is best to communicate on the basis that this is not an act of malice. You can write the authors of these papers (and authors of preprints on the topic) a polite email stating that you liked their interesting work and have done related work that you think might be of interest to them. What they do with that information is up to them then.

Comment: For the interested, here's a couple of those extreme cases described on Retraction Watch: [Example 1](https://retractionwatch.com/2014/04/10/lack-of-citation-prompts-correction-in-nature-journal/), and [Example 2](https://retractionwatch.com/2016/12/15/not-citation-police-no-errata-omitted-citations-says-economics-journal/).

Answer (score 12):

What do you expect to see in references? Every article on the topic?

References should contain the articles that the article in question actually reference. They publish some results. If these results are in the area that those "well known" articles defined and set up - they reference those. If they use certain results found in other articles - they reference those. But they don't owe you a reference just because you do similar stuff in parallel. If your results weren't used in their work, there's nothing to reference.

If they are writing a survey, they should include every notable result and reference it. If this is the case, you could actually contact them and ask (in a non-aggressive manner) why your work hasn't been included. But everyday articles should just cite the articles that they base the work on.

If you suspect they simply don't know about your work, feel free to write something friendly like "hey, looks like we are working on the same stuff, I noticed that you found Fact1 about Topic1 in Article1, I managed to find Fact2 in Article2. do you think Fact3 could be true? have you managed to do any work on that yet?"

Comment: I strongly disagree with the second paragraph. If you are writing a paper about doing X, and there was a publicly available and reviewed paper doing X (or a very closed task X'), then you *have* to reference and discuss it. You cannot just keep reinventing already known stuff and claim it as new ignoring the past work of everyone else.

Comment: @ClementC. I disagree.  You should only reference what you need/used for your paper.  The existence of a paper doing the same thing if anything should merely be reason for an editor to reject the publication of your paper if they agree it is too similar to the previously published work.

Comment: I couldn't disagree more... I don't know what your field of research is, but in mine omitting citations in the "Relevant work" section is a major sin.

Comment: @ClementC your field has a section of the bibliography called "Relevant Work"? We literally call ours "Work Cited", if we don't cite it, we don't include it. Not having read every single article is common. Even the best Cervantista will find it impossible to have read every single work on Cervantes, so *even if* you felt citation were mandatory, I wouldn't call the lack of it a sin, because that implies that it is possible to (a) know if every single article in existence on the topic, (b) have access to them all and (c) read them all.

Comment: @guifa No, we have a part of the *introduction* for this discussion. And my fiels is theoretical computer science (the OP states theirs is computer science), so close to math. If you prove a "new" theorem and don't cite a paper from the year before who already has shown the same result or something similar, then you have a problem. You should have read it, discussed it, and cited it, you cannot ignore the fact that the theorem (or algorithm, or result, etc) was already known.

Comment: @ClementC The OP isn't talking about a new discovery, simply "related work". If the paper claimed a discovery that was published several years prior, it doesn't matter whether they cited or referenced the previous work, the editor should not have let the paper past their desk. Ultimately, if the paper were truly that relevant and fundamental, I'm sure the editor would have noted it and requested or demanded its inclusion.

Comment: @guifa I am not sure we are on the same page with regard to what constitutes a discovery in computer science, theoretical computer science, or related fields. A new method/algorithm that performs a given task with better accuracy or time complexity than the others is a discovery. Showing "Task X can be performed in time blah to achieve guarantee bleh with my algorithm" is a discovery (if previous work had worse running time or accuracy).

Comment: @clementC Where we place the semantic bounds of "discovery" is moot.  At the end of the day, if it were actually important for the author to cite article X, *the editor should have required its inclusion*. Relevancy is subjective, and minor advances to a subfield may not actually need be cited in every single paper in the subfield here on out, absent literally being quoted. The editor clearly felt that the paper was fine as is. The OP isn't claiming the other paper plagiarized or falsely claimed credit for anything, so I don't see  how you can be so sure an extraneous citation is so needed.

Comment: @guifa To be frank? CS is conference-based, with short review times. I do not necessarily share your faith in the editor (in this case, reviewers and PC members). But my point is -- editor aside, if the OP's claims are true, then they **should** have been cited. Your whole point now basically boils down to "The OP must not be right in their claim [their work is relevant], or the editor would have caught it." That's changing the whole premise of the answer.

Comment: @ClementC. I think we have a different understanding of the problem here.I agree that if you find an algorithm that does X in n^2.15 time you should discuss and compare it to the previous result that same in n^2.18. I read the question more like "we investigated the P=NP problem from the [..] viewpoint. The problem was set up by the famous papers [x] and [y]" and that might not need to reference everyone (or maybe no one at all) working on P=NP in the last few years.

Comment: @Džuris With that reading, sure. But then, well, there is no real scenario someone could actually call their own work relevant without blushing, I reckon.